# Origin and pronunciation of "Thawte"

Tags: meaning, etymology, pronunciation

Working in the IT industry I often have to use the word *Thawte* - the name of [a company](http://www.thawte.com/) and its certificates. What is the origin of this word and its correct pronunciation? Does it have its own meaning or is it just a name? A web search result seems to contain IT security stuff only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe Thawte constructed its name as a portmanteau of "thought" and "[thwart](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thwart)", which would make sense considering their area of expertise. I would imagine that "Thawte" was intended to be pronounced the same way as you would pronounce "thought".

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: @NateEldredge - No, hence my tone - "I believe", "I would imagine".

Comment: My South African friend just informed me that Thawte are based in SA, and a lot of South Africans would struggle to pronounce the *thw-* part of "thwart", and would say "thawt" instead.

Comment: @Polynomial, yes that's the initial company of Mark Shuttleworth of Ubuntu/Canical fame. I think he sold it for half a billion usd to Verisign.

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard anyone say it, but all the references I can find say to pronounce the name as "thought".